# How can I add CSS to a content page without modifying master page?

Tags: css, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

We have a masterpage for many webforms. The CSS of all these webforms is in the masterpage.

This one particular webform will use the same masterpage, but I don't want to add the CSS of this webform to the masterpage.

Considering that this page is temporary, I want to add CSS to my content page without touching the masterpage.

Is it possible to add CSS to a content page without touching the masterpage?

I do have a `ContentPlaceHolder` in the `<head>` of my master page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `ContentPlaceHolder` in the `<head>` section of your Master Page. So, the only thing you need to do is to specify your CSS file in this `ContentPlaceHolder` of your content page that uses your Master Page (no changes in your Master Page):

```
<asp:Content ID="contentHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <link href="fileName.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</asp:Content>
```

Or you can use inline style:

```
<asp:Content ID="contentHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <style>
        .yourClass { ... }
    </stlye>
</asp:Content>
```

When your page is rendered, the CSS of your content page will be applied after the CSS of the Master Page.

Comment: can you also add `inline styling` to your answer? Since I'm using  inline styling instead of a css file. That way I'll erase my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i understand your question. But you can include CSS inline elements and give a particular id/class to your webform.

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
  .webform1{...}
</style>
```

If that is not what you need, please specify your question.

Comment: I want to add CSS to my content page without touching the masterpage.

Comment: @rbhatup You can add that CSS to your content page. CSS doesn't *have* to be in the `<head>` of your page, although it's good practice to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a placeholder in the master page within the head section:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Header" runat="server" />
```

Then you could use a content tag:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Header" Runat="Server">  
     <link...>
</asp:Content>
```

on the content page, and put the css file reference inside it. Then it will just load on that page.

Comment: and instead of referencing a css file, you could also put just css inside <style> tags within the content tags.

Comment: But I don't want to modify the masterpage for this content page.

Comment: You will have to touch the masterpage - but that won't cause any problem else where if you use content placeholders. The only other option would be to seperate it from the masterpage as a stand alone webform. Then add the same file references in the header etc.

Comment: @rbhatup Why don't you want to modify the master page? What's the reasoning behind that?

Comment: @mason Why should he modify the Master Page? Does he need to?

Comment: You can add the css in `content1`of the content page, and it will be read: `<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<style type="text/css">
   .withSpace
   {
       padding-left:310px;
   }
</style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">`

Comment: @krlzlx I'm trying to find out *why* he doesn't want to modify it. If he doesn't have a content place holder in the head of his master page, then he should put one there for situations like this. And I can't think of a good reason not to do so if it's not already done.

Comment: @tigerdi, you don't need to touch the masterpage to add css to a content page.

Comment: @rbhatup No, you don't. But why do you want to avoid it so much?

Comment: @mason Yes I agree with you but I asked and he replied: _"Yes, I have a ContentPlaceHolder in <head> of the master page"_

Comment: @krlzlx Fair enough, I missed that comment. I've added it to the main question.